# Insert data from one database table to another database table in the same server

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I wrote this query using MYSQL work bench for insert data into one database to another database, but it doesn't work,can you help me to solve this problem

```
USE att2000;
```

create trigger trgAfterInsert
after insert on CHECKINOUT for each row

```
INSERT INTO orangehrm_mysql.ohrm_attendance_record(employee_id,punch_in_utc_time) values(USERID,CHECKTIME);
SELECT 
    checkinout.USERID, checkinout.CHECKTIME
FROM
    CHECKINOUT
WHERE
HOUR(CHECKTIME) < 12;



INSERT INTO orangehrm_mysql.ohrm_attendance_record(employee_id,punch_out_user_time) values(USERID,CHECKTIME);
SELECT 
    checkinout.USERID, checkinout.CHECKTIME
FROM
    CHECKINOUT
WHERE
HOUR(CHECKTIME) >= 12;
```

Comment: the name of the 1st database is `orangehrm_mysql`, what is the name of the second database? i am giving you a hint on how to solve your issue

Comment: second data base att2000

Answer (score 0):

Try without `values`

```
 INSERT INTO orangehrm_mysql.ohrm_attendance_record(employee_id,punch_in_utc_time) 
 (    
    SELECT 
        checkinout.USERID, checkinout.CHECKTIME
    FROM
        CHECKINOUT
    WHERE
    HOUR(CHECKTIME) < 12
 );



INSERT INTO orangehrm_mysql.ohrm_attendance_record(employee_id,punch_out_user_time) 
(
    SELECT 
        checkinout.USERID, checkinout.CHECKTIME
    FROM
        CHECKINOUT
    WHERE
    HOUR(CHECKTIME) >= 12
);
```

Comment: I Put Values Also But Same Result    -INSERT INTO orangehrm_mysql.ohrm_attendance_record(employee_id,punch_out_user_time) values(USERID,CHECKTIME);
SELECT 
    checkinout.USERID, checkinout.CHECKTIME
FROM
    CHECKINOUT
WHERE
HOUR(CHECKTIME) >= 12;

Comment: Try this instead. You have tried the same code you posted. @KanjulaKumara

Comment: I put values(USERID,CHECKTIME)

Answer (score 0):

here you go:

```
INSERT INTO orangehrm_mysql.ohrm_attendance_record(employee_id,punch_in_utc_time) 
    (
       SELECT co.USERID, co.CHECKTIME
       FROM att2000.CHECKINOUT co
       WHERE HOUR(co.CHECKTIME) < 12
    );



INSERT INTO orangehrm_mysql.ohrm_attendance_record(employee_id,punch_out_user_time) 
    (
        SELECT co.USERID, co.CHECKTIME
        FROM att2000.CHECKINOUT co
        WHERE HOUR(co.CHECKTIME) >= 12
    );
```

Comment: Hi Luthando Loot,When Run this query it's insert Data into only one punch_in_utc_time,Other Part doesn't work,can you tell me why

Comment: go to this database `att2000` and check if `USERID` is the correct column.  Don't you have `employee_id` instead of `USERID`?

Comment: UserID Containing On att2000.CHECKINOUT And employee_id IS On orangehrm_mysql.ohrm_attendance_record TABLE,       BUTatt2000.CHECKINOUT.UserID=orangehrm_mysql.ohrm_attendance_record.employee_id

Comment: make you copy the exact column name, that will fix it

Comment: i split first insert part and run separate ly it's working like that,so nothing wrong with the coloum names, i want to make a trigger like this

Comment: this looks right to me, what error are you getting?